# Extracting view to function or struct?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to learning Swift and SwiftUI. I have a struct with a View which contains a VStack. Within the VStack, I'm calling four functions which return a View.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        self.renderLogo()
        self.renderUserNameTextField()
        self.renderPasswordSecureField()
        self.renderLoginButton()
        
    }
}

func renderLoginButton() -> some View {
    return Button(action: {print("Button clicked")}){
        Text("LOGIN").font(.headline).foregroundColor(.white).padding().frame(width: 220, height: 60).background(Color(red: 0, green: 70/255, blue: 128/255)).cornerRadius(15.0)
    }.padding()
}[...]
```

I've just read that it's more common that views are extracted to a struct like that:

```
struct UsernameTextField : View {
@Binding var username: String
var body: some View {
return TextField("Username", text: $username)
            .padding()
            .background(lightGreyColor)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
}
```

Why is that? What advantages are there using structs instead of a normal function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This raises an interesting point. You don't want to make large views by having standard controls with lots of modifiers, but you want some kind of reuse, either by using a function to return the view or a custom view.

When I face these problems in SwiftUI I look to see what I am extracting. In your case it looks like the controls are standard, but they have different styling applied to them. The clue is in the function names that all have `render`.

In this case, rather than using a function or a custom View, I would write a custom modifier that applies a set of common styles to a control. A couple of examples from your code:

First, create ViewModifiers

```swift
struct InputTextFieldModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding()
            .background(Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
}


struct ButtonTextModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
            .background(Color(red: 0, green: 70/255, blue: 128/255))
            .cornerRadius(15.0)
    }
}
```

These are quite simple to write. You just apply the modifiers you want to the content parameter.

And to make them easier to use, you can write extension to `View`

```swift
extension View {
    func inputTextFieldStyle() -> some View {
        modifier(InputTextFieldModifier())
    }

    func buttonTextStyle() -> some View {
        modifier(ButtonTextModifier())
    }
}
```

And this makes the call site look something like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        ...
        TextField(...)
            .inputTextFieldStyle()
        ...
        Button(action: {print("Button clicked")}){
            Text("LOGIN")
                .buttonTextStyle()
        }.padding()
        
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to configure the modifier, that is easy as well. Say you want to specify the background colour of your common text fields, you can re-write the modifier to take this as a parameter:

```swift
struct InputTextFieldModifier: ViewModifier {
    let backgroundColor: Color

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding()
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
}
```

And update your convenience function to take this as a parameter:

```swift
extension View {
    func inputTextFieldStyle(backgroundColor: Color) -> some View {
        modifier(InputTextFieldModifier(backgroundColor: backgroundColor))
    }
}
```

And at the call site:

```swift
TextField("Username", text: $username)
    .inputTextFieldStyle(backgroundColor: Color.gray)
```

And custom modifiers are reusable.

Comment: Excellent! I agree with you that using a custom `ViewModifier` is a better option to apply multiple SwiftUI's view-modifiers to style a `View` rather than using a custom `View`.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I would separate a view in a different struct if that view will have at least a `@Binding` with the main view. Otherwise, I would stick to functions. But...

It's up to you if you want to do it in separate structs or in a function but take into account that if you want to **reuse a view**, is easier if you have it declared as a separate entity.

Another purpose of this is to **avoid having enormous views** in SwiftUI, separating the responsibilities into smaller views makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more advised to extract your `views` to `structs`, thus you can later reuse your views in your code, keeping your code more clean and isolated.

Comment: One example of doing this is at the Hacking with Swift site, at:
[link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-and-compose-custom-views)
I think there's too much code there to include here, and copyright concerns, but it shows the syntax for creating subview structs.

Comment: And another example of creating sub-view structs is at Swift by Sundell at [link](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/avoiding-massive-swiftui-views/):
https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/avoiding-massive-swiftui-views